# Model Deployment - Pricing Information

Tags: azure, chatgpt-api, azure-openai

We are creating some models in Azure Open AI Studio and doing deployments of same. I want to check how much charges are applied for model creation, deployments and requests made to deployed model. I am unable to find a dashboard where I can check it. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below link and it lands you in Cost Management + Billing section there you can find the cost analysis to see detailed information about your consumption. Choose the subscription or resource group relevant to your OpenAI services.

[https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_GTM/ModernBillingMenuBlade/~/BillingAccounts](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_GTM/ModernBillingMenuBlade/%7E/BillingAccounts)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?terms=openai%20Cost%20Management%20and%20Billing&category=QnA

Comment: Thanks for sharing the links. I am not able to see data. Its showing "None of the entries matched the given filter."
Probably I don't have required access to view data.

Comment: In this case check if you have the roles required in case not you can ask ur manager or admin to grant you the roles.

Answer (score 0):

Please select the region in the [Azure Open AI pricing Page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/openai-service/), and Pricing will be based on the pay-as-you-go consumption model with a price per unit for each model, which is similar to other Azure AI Services pricing models.
Here is the [blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ai-azure-ai-services-blog/azure-openai-service-launches-gpt-4-turbo-and-gpt-3-5-turbo-1106/ba-p/3985962) for the new ones.

[image]